# TYPO3 pagetree: red plus sign?

Tags: icons, typo3, backend

in TYPO3 10.4.x appeared a red plus sign in pagetree. What does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reminder that this page has set the option "**Hide child pages in page tree**" `(php_tree_stop)` (set on tab `Behaviour`, in group `Miscellaneous`)

There are child pages to that page which are not available in the complete page tree any more.

If you click on the `+` Sign you will get just that subtree as working page tree (and a button to end this view mode).